# T-SQL Create a view in a stored procedure using dynamic sql

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a stored procedure which pivots query results and creates corresponding views. I'm stuck at the point where it actually creates views. Please see the code below

I've already tried with **execute(), sp_executesql()**.

If in an initial **@query** we don't have any variables then the following code works:

```
execute ('create view  AzureDataCatalog.temp AS ' + @query).
```

I have to make it work with variables.

```
DECLARE @iterator INT = 0


declare @n int = (
                SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT c.name)  AS [ColumnName]
                FROM    sys.views  v 
                        INNER JOIN sys.all_columns c ON v.object_id = c.object_id
                        INNER JOIN sys.schemas s ON v.schema_id = s.schema_id
                )

WHILE @iterator< @n
BEGIN

Declare @cols nvarchar(max)
Declare @query nvarchar(max)

Select @cols = stuff((select ','+QuoteName([ColumnName]) from 
(
    SELECT  DISTINCT c.name  AS [ColumnName]
    FROM    sys.views  v 
            INNER JOIN sys.all_columns c ON v.object_id = c.object_id
            INNER JOIN sys.schemas s ON v.schema_id = s.schema_id
    ORDER BY [ColumnName] 
    OFFSET @iterator ROWS
    FETCH NEXT 1000 ROWS ONLY
) tb

    for xml path('')),1,1,'')
Select @query = N' Select * from (
    Select [ColumnName], RowN = Row_Number() over (order by [ColumnName]) 
    FROM 
        (
            SELECT  DISTINCT c.name  AS [ColumnName]
            FROM    sys.views  v 
                INNER JOIN sys.all_columns c ON v.object_id = c.object_id
                INNER JOIN sys.schemas s ON v.schema_id = s.schema_id
            ORDER BY [ColumnName] 
            OFFSET @iterator ROWS
            FETCH NEXT 1000 ROWS ONLY
        ) tb
    ) a
    pivot (MAX([RowN]) for [ColumnName] in (' + @cols + ')) p '

Exec sp_executesql @query, N'@iterator INT', @iterator


DECLARE @iteratorName NVARCHAR(20)
SET @iteratorName = CONVERT(NVARCHAR(20), @iterator)

DECLARE @viewName VARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @sqlCommand NVARCHAR(100)
SET @viewName = 'temp' + @iteratorName

-- Check if the view exists
IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM sys.views WHERE name = @viewName)
BEGIN
    SET @sqlCommand = 'SELECT ''Yes'''
    EXEC(@sqlCommand)

    execute ('drop view  AzureDataCatalog.temp' + @iteratorName)

    -- This code works, if there aren't any variables inside @query
    execute ('create view  AzureDataCatalog.temp' + @iteratorName +' AS ' + @query)
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    SET @sqlCommand = 'SELECT ''No'''
    EXEC(@sqlCommand)

    SET @sqlCommand = 'create view  AzureDataCatalog.temp' + @iteratorName +' AS ' + @query

    Exec sp_executesql @query, N'@iterator INT', @iterator
END

SET @iterator += 1024


/*Execute a Stored Procedure*/
END
```

Basically, I need to get the following code working:

```
DECLARE @sqlCommand NVARCHAR(100)
SET @sqlCommand = 'create view  AzureDataCatalog.temp' + @iteratorName +' AS ' + @query

Exec sp_executesql @query, N'@iterator INT', @iterator
```

But instead I get a following error

```
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'view'.
```

Comment: You cannot pass in identifiers using parameters.  This includes "constructing" the names from parameters.

Comment: @GordonLinoff How else can I create views dynamically? They need to be created inside the loop

Answer (score 0):

To change identifiers, you need to munge the query string, which you seem to basically be doing.  Just to be clear, store the view name you want in a string and use that in your code:

```
DECLARE @iteratorName NVARCHAR(20);
SET @iteratorName = CONVERT(NVARCHAR(20), @iterator);

DECLARE @viewName VARCHAR(100);
DECLARE @sqlCommand NVARCHAR(100);
SET @viewName = 'temp' + @iteratorName;

SET @sqlCommand = 'create view ' + @viewName + ' AS ' + @query;

EXEC sp_executesql @query;
```

Comment: But the problem is not with view names but with the execution of sqlCommand itself. If I run `EXEC sp_executesql @sqlCommand` ; then I get following error  `Msg 10753, Level 15, State 3, Procedure temp0, Line 2 [Batch Start Line 0]
The function 'Row_Number' must have an OVER clause.`

Comment: @kido25 . . . Fix the syntax by running the query not as a view and not as dynamic SQL.  Then when it works, create the dynamic SQL.